# Solution of $y''-y'=xe^x$ using Method of Undetermined Coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem gives $y''-y'=xe^x$ with conditions $y(0)=2$ and $y'\left(0\right)=1$.

My issue is when calculating the particular solution of the equation. I assumed that it should take the form $y_p=(Ax+B)e^x$. After substituting into the 2nd ODE, it becomes:

$(2A+Ax+B)e^x-(A+Ax+B)e^x=xe^x$

This simplifies to $Ae^x=xe^x$. I'm not sure how to progress. Is $A=0$? This does not seem like the correct way to proceed with solving the problem but I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Try $(Ax^2+Bx+C)e^x$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Why wouldn't it take the form $(Ax+B)e^x$ though?

Comment: I thought you'd just **proved** why not.

Comment: It doesn't take the form $(Ax + B)e^x because of the second derivative.

Comment: The reason you don't have $(Ax+B)e^x$ is that $e^x$ is already a solution to the homogeneous equation $y''-y'=0$, so you need to find another term to use instead.

Answer (score 1):

If I may suggest, proceed by step.

Start using $y'=u$ to have $$y''-y'=xe^x\implies u'-u=xe^x$$ Now let $u=v e^x$ to get $$v' e^x=x e^x \implies v'=x\implies v=\frac 12 x^2+c_1$$ Here, you already see that the solution will contain an $x^2$ term somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

For any Problem First try taking the RHS as y, In this case y=xe^x. Substitute in the LHS, If you get the answer as 0 then your guess is simply not compatible, It should be yp=(Ax+B)xe^x. To be exact you should multiply your guess by x until you find a different league of terms than in the LHS.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).